# ImportXML google sheet for shipment package tracking

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to track each FEDEX, DHL and UPS shipment status directly from google sheets. I am using importxml function:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers="&C2&"&locale=en_US&cntry_code=us","//h1/div[@class="redesignSnapshotTVC snapshotController_addr_label dest"]/title")

However it shows error.
Attaching my sheet link for this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1L0rn9-H4MCutI1On2uHDkkPo1pdjRpv014YREGIdU/edit?usp=sharing

Please tell what is best way to do it. I am from non tech background.
Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 1):

Common issue. You're trying to import html that is generated after loading. That means we have to look for how the data you want is generated.

### Data source

Upon inspection of the site, I found that it was making an XHR to the URL `https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track`, and that it was doing so via POST with a long payload. The response was in JSON format. Of note, there is the `scanEventList` entry.

```json
"scanEventList": [{
    "date": "2020-07-15",
    "time": "13:15:00",
    "gmtOffset": "-07:00",
    "status": "Delivery exception",
    "statusCD": "DE",
    "scanLocation": "SAN BERNARDINO, CA",
    "scanDetails": "Future delivery requested",
    "scanDetailsHtml": "",
    "rtrnShprTrkNbr": "",
    "statusExceptionCode": "17",
    "isClearanceDelay": false,
    "isDelivered": false,
    "isDelException": true,
    "isException": true
},
...
]
```

### Solution

First, get the [ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) script from GitHub, and add it into your sheet's scripts (Tools > Script Editor). It's not the most amazing thing, but it will at least give us `ImportJSONViaPost()` to get the data we want:

```
=INDEX(ImportJSONViaPost("https://www.fedex.com/trackingCal/track","data=%7B%22TrackPackagesRequest%22%3A%7B%22appType%22%3A%22WTRK%22%2C%22appDeviceType%22%3A%22DESKTOP%22%2C%22supportHTML%22%3Atrue%2C%22supportCurrentLocation%22%3Atrue%2C%22uniqueKey%22%3A%22%22%2C%22processingParameters%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22trackingInfoList%22%3A%5B%7B%22trackNumberInfo%22%3A%7B%22trackingNumber%22%3A%22"&A2&"%22%2C%22trackingQualifier%22%3A%22%22%2C%22trackingCarrier%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D&action=trackpackages&locale=en_US&version=1&format=json",,"/TrackPackagesResponse/packageList/scanEventList,/TrackPackagesResponse/packageList/trackingCarrierDesc","noHeaders"),1)
```

Arguments:

1. URL for the tracker
2. The POST payload. Cell A2 Holds your tracking number.
3. Leave empty
4. Query - Lets us select the data that we want. In this example, I chose to select the carrier description and the entire `scanEventList` entry, but you can specify particular elements of that as well.
5. "noHeaders" means just the data.

Just using the JSON import gives us an entry for each element of `scanEventList`, but the first is the most recent, so, we use `INDEX` to retrieve the first entry, which should contain what you need.

For additional help on the ImportJSON package, see [here](https://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json).